# refind not showing after Windows 10 Update

Tags: refind

I had refind boot manager working on my macbook since today when I received a critical Windows 10 update.

How do I fix it without loosing Windows Boot?

Comment: See the [boot coup page of the rEFInd documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) If that doesn't help, please provide more details, such as what happens when you try to boot and what procedure(s) from the boot coup page you've tried and what the result(s) were.

Comment: Can I reinstall refind will that work? @RodSmith

Comment: Mount partition and install the script again?

Comment: From the page I referenced: "The most general, and in some cases the easiest, solution to a boot coup is to re-install rEFInd."

Comment: @RodSmith I re-installed in OSX. Then it was working again but it stopped working again once I booted in Windows. How to report problem? I can't figure out what's the problem and how to report it

Answer (score 3):

Windows removing other boot loader entries is a known, although not universal, problem. See [this question and my answer to it on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) for a bit more information. In brief, using `bcdedit` in Windows usually fixes the problem:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
```

You'd type this in an Administrator Command Prompt window. This assumes that rEFInd is installed in the usual location on the ESP.

One caveat: This procedure is known to work on UEFI-based PCs. Because Macs are different, there may be an extra twist that will cause this procedure to fail. If so, you might try creating a small HFS+ partition, installing to it using the `--ownhfs` option to `refind-install`, and then using macOS's tool to set that as the default boot option if Windows misbehaves again.

Comment: I have installed refind in MacOS in EFI path not in Windows. So how do I find `Path to Bootmgr`

Comment: The standard rEFInd install location is as specified in my suggested command -- `\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi`. If it's someplace else you'd probably know (unless you used the `--ownhfs` option to `refind-install`).